# Querying Data from Raspberry Pi MySQL database through Android App

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, raspberry-pi

I am working on a hardware/software project that involves Arduino, Raspberry Pi, and Android.

Right now, I am trying to figure out how to query data from a MySQL database that is on the RPi server with the Android app, which I will later display in a layout.

Being relatively new to databases and Android, I looked up tutorials, but many of them go through a user sign-in/sign-up example. I do not need the app to write to the database (our Arduino microcontroller is taking care of that), I only need the app to query it to display information on the app. Trying to extract that exact information has proven more difficult than expected, and I am still trying to piece parts of tutorials together to get what I need.

More specifically, I've gathered that I will need some PHP scripts on the RPi, but I'm not certain what the URL is that my app will have to make an HTTP request. Some tutorials say to use JDBC (which I don't entirely understand either) and others have the URL simply be "http://RaspberryPi_IP/some_php_script", so I'm not sure which is right.

I think an answer to the URL issue would be a good start, but I would also appreciate any other guidance on this process as a whole. In the meantime, I will continue researching and figuring this out. Thank you!

Comment: You can either use JDBC so that you access the MySQL database directly from the Android device without any PHP, or you can write a frontend to your database using PHP, and request the data from that in Android. Usually, people don't access database directly from Android device, but that's up to you.

Comment: So this URL, "http://RaspberryPi_IP/some_php_script", is okay? And this will ideally return the data in JSON, which I will have to parse and interpret, correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.